# How to associate EOL escape sequence with a specific file?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to associate `"files.eol": "\n"` parameter in settings with js file. I tried to set `"[javascript]": { "files.eol": "\n" }` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. However the VS Code Team is aware of it. You can track and vote for the corresponding feature request [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/39051).